# What is the word for a method with the following limitations

Tags: java

Is there a name for the type of method in Java that does not reply upon dynamic information from outside that method?

- Class variables would not be ok.
- Referring to variables in other classes would not be ok, even using getters.

Per comments below, this method must have no side effects.

Would this be an Idempotent method?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand, but "pure" sounds right. Are you saying it only relies on its parameters, or doesn't take any parameters?

Comment: [Pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)

Comment: With "Class variables" you mean also instance variables (non static fields)?

Comment: @AndyTurner I really wonder why everybody calls this *pure*. There's no reason for that. The function could have side-effects or destroy args. Example: `Function<List<?>, Integer> f = l -> {int size = l.size(); l.clear(); return size;};` - fits the description, isn't pure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the information  It seems a pure function.

Definition of pure function is :

> A function is called pure function if it always returns the same
>   result for same argument values and it has no side effects like
>   modifying an argument (or global variable) or outputting something.
>   The only result of calling a pure function is the return value.
>   Examples of pure functions are strlen(), pow(), sqrt() etc.

Please have a look at this article.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-functions/

Comment: Which part of the description indicates that the method does not have side effects?